# Configuring the Amazon MySQL RDS for 30GB database backup file restore

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am planing to restore the MySQL DB dump file in MySQL amazon RDS instance. I would like to get some suggestions on configuring the MySQL RDS instance in order to make the MySQL DB backup (30GB size) to complete successfully. Last time I tried 3GB backup file restore with m4large instance With 8GB RAM. But the time of restore the memory reached its threshold and stopped the process. So this time  I would like to get clear MySQL RDS instance configuration to accept 30GB backup restore. Please give me some suggestion on this

Answer (score 1):

If you have a smaller instance still you can backup large data if somehow you can break the data or the process into smaller steps. You can look for a way to break the whole data into smaller chunks while backing up. Using any tool which can allow you to break the whole data into chunks. 
CHUNKs have effect on the (source) server from where data are exported. The CHUNK size is specified in number of rows. If for instance a chunk size of 1000 rows is specified then data will not simply be fetched using one 'SELECT ...' but more SELECTs like 'SELECT ..LIMIT 1,1000', 'SELECT ... LIMIT 1001,1000' will be used until the end of data is reached. This assures that is it possible to specify a CHUNK size that does not exceed various types of resources ( like the memory available) to user ... what would result in very slow operation or even maybe a 'hang' or 'deadlock'. Also specifying a not too big CHUNK setting will ensure that no timeout will occur. Such timeout may happen due to server 'net_write_timeout' setting or network settings not specifically related to MySQL.

Also the size of the bulk can help you to determine the maximum size of the saved file. Basically you will have to experiment a little by yourself to find the settings that are optimal for you - and they of course may be different with different hosting providers if you have more. A practical experience with most cheap hosting is that CHUNKs setting of 2000-10000 (rows - depending on how many and what type of columns you have)

Comment: Thanks Walter for your reply.
Sorry, I have taken the MySQL backup file successfully with 10GB size. But the problem is while restoring the DB into RDS. We need to get MySQL RDS configuration to accept the 10GB backup file size to restore. Please help me on this

Comment: That is what my answer was intended to tell. If you break it into chunks of smaller sizes, then you wont need larger RAM. I am unaware of any settings in RDS that might help you to achieve what you are trying..